# Регулярное выражение [a-z]+

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, intellij-idea

Почему регулярка `[a-z]+` в **Idea** не ищет букву из диапазона `a-z`, в то время как на https://regexr.ru/ нормально находит?

```
public static boolean checkTelNumber(String telNumber) {
    if (telNumber.matches("[a-z]+")) return false;

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkTelNumber("2345asd2345da"));
}
```

Comment: Так проверять телефонный номер - это какой-то бред...

Comment: Смысл не в проверке номера. Смысл - научиться регулярным выражениям.

Comment: Смысл в том, что проверка через исключение - почти всегда ерунда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что метод [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) ищет полное совпадение строки с шаблоном.

Вот так будет работать:

```
System.out.println(checkTelNumber("asdda"));
```

---

Если нужен поиск по регулярке, тогда:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
java.util.regex.Matcher m = pattern.matcher("2345asd2345da");
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Консоль:

```
asd
da
```

Answer (score 1):

Она как раз ищет, только для метода matches должно соответствовать все выражение регулярному выражению вам подойдет или так:

```
public static boolean checkTelNumber(String telNumber) {
    return !telNumber.matches("\\w+");
}
```

или так:

```
public static boolean checkTelNumber(String telNumber) {
    return !telNumber.matches("[a-z0-9]+");
}
```